# Move multiple 'day' columns to rows and merge with date column in Python without duplicating date and extending the range of the df

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pivot, melt

I have a df with the following precipitation data:

`Year Month  Model  Day 1  Day 2  Day 3  Day 4  Day 5  Day 7 ... Day 31                      0  2006    1  CNRM   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00  ... 0.00                      1  2006    2  CNRM   0.00   5.47   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.01  ... 5.34                       2  2006    3  CNRM   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00  ... 1.88                       3  2006    4  CNRM   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.01  ... 1.12                      4  2006    5  CNRM   1.56   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00  ... 6.37`

What I need is to move the 31 'Day' columns to an unic 'Day' column and later combine the three date columns (Year, Month and Day) in a single 'Date' column.

I wanted to try 'melt' and  'pivot':

```
x = data.melt(['Year','Month','Model'])

x = x.pivot(index = ['Year','Month'],columns = ['Model'],values = 'Precipitation').reset_index()
```

but I get an error when pivoting because the index is duplicated.

What I don't know is how can I extend the length of the df to get a daily date column and move each day column value to the correspondent place in row.

Comment: Use `pivot_table`